# RRWEB reading recorded events not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save a browser user activity using an open source tool [RRWEB](https://www.rrweb.io/)

I'm able to save events generated by the tool (recording). The code I used is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recorder</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@1.0.3/dist/rrweb.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@1.0.3/dist/record/rrweb-record.js"></script>
        <script>
            let events = [];
            rrwebRecord({
              emit(event) {
                // push event into the events array
                events.push(event);
              }
            });

            // this function will send events to the backend and reset the events array
            function save() {
                    const body = JSON.stringify({ 
                        events: events
                    });
                    events = [];
                    fetch('recorder.php', {
                      mode: 'no-cors',
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      },
                      body
                    });
            }
            // save events every 5 seconds
            setInterval(save, 5 * 1000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
                <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The console shows the following objects sent to my back-end script:

```
{"events":[{"type":0,"data":{},"timestamp":1630354988708},{"type":1,"data":{},"timestamp":1630354988711},{"type":4,"data":{"href":"https://track.mobiuslogistics.biz/","width":741,"height":615},"timestamp":1630354988712},{"type":2,"data":{"node":{"type":0,"childNodes":[{"type":1,"name":"html","publicId":"","systemId":"","id":2},{"type":5,"textContent":"\nTo change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.\nTo change this template file, choose Tools | Templates\nand open the template in the editor.\n","id":3},{"type":2,"tagName":"html","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":2,"tagName":"head","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":6},{"type":2,"tagName":"title","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"Recorder","id":8}],"id":7},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":9},{"type":2,"tagName":"meta","attributes":{"charset":"UTF-8"},"childNodes":[],"id":10},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":11},{"type":2,"tagName":"meta","attributes":{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"},"childNodes":[],"id":12},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":13},{"type":2,"tagName":"link","attributes":{"_cssText":".replayer-wrapper { position: relative; }.replayer-mouse { position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 20px; transition: left 0.05s linear 0s, top 0.05s linear 0s; background-size: contain; background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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\"); border-color: transparent; }.replayer-mouse::after { content: \"\"; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: rgb(73, 80, 246) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 100%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); opacity: 0.3; }.replayer-mouse.active::after { animation: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal none running click; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device { background-image: none; width: 70px; height: 70px; border-radius: 100%; margin-left: -37px; margin-top: -37px; border: 4px solid rgba(73, 80, 246, 0); transition: left 0s linear 0s, top 0s linear 0s, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device.touch-active { border-color: rgb(73, 80, 246); transition: left 0.25s linear 0s, top 0.25s linear 0s, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device::after { opacity: 0; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device.active::after { animation: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal none running touch-click; }.replayer-mouse-tail { position: absolute; pointer-events: none; }@keyframes click {\n0% { opacity: 0.3; width: 20px; height: 20px; }\n50% { opacity: 0.5; width: 10px; height: 10px; }\n}@keyframes touch-click {\n0% { opacity: 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; }\n50% { opacity: 0.5; width: 10px; height: 10px; }\n}"},"childNodes":[],"id":14},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":15},{"type":2,"tagName":"script","attributes":{"src":"https://track.mobiuslogistics.biz/js/rrweb-record.js"},"childNodes":[],"id":16},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":17},{"type":2,"tagName":"script","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"SCRIPT_PLACEHOLDER","id":19}],"id":18},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    ","id":20}],"id":5},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    ","id":21},{"type":2,"tagName":"body","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":23},{"type":2,"tagName":"div","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n            ","id":25},{"type":2,"tagName":"form","attributes":{"action":"/action_page.php"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":27},{"type":2,"tagName":"label","attributes":{"for":"fname"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"First name:","id":29}],"id":28},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":30},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":31},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"text","id":"fname","name":"fname","value":"John"},"childNodes":[],"id":32},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":33},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":34},{"type":2,"tagName":"label","attributes":{"for":"lname"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"Last name:","id":36}],"id":35},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":37},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":38},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"text","id":"lname","name":"lname","value":"Doe"},"childNodes":[],"id":39},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":40},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":41},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":42},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"submit","value":"Submit"},"childNodes":[],"id":43},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n            ","id":44}],"id":26},{"type":3,"textContent":" \n        ","id":45}],"id":24},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    \n\n","id":46}],"id":22}],"id":4}],"id":1},"initialOffset":{"left":0,"top":0}},"timestamp":1630354988721},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":1},"timestamp":1630354988723},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":348,"y":208,"id":4,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1630354988725},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":378,"y":169,"id":4,"timeOffset":-415},{"x":372,"y":165,"id":4,"timeOffset":-167},{"x":192,"y":99,"id":26,"timeOffset":-117},{"x":104,"y":74,"id":39,"timeOffset":-67},{"x":95,"y":59,"id":26,"timeOffset":-16}]},"timestamp":1630354989233},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":1,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989556},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354989556},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":0,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989642},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":2,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989642},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":81,"y":46,"id":32,"timeOffset":-469},{"x":53,"y":31,"id":32,"timeOffset":-418},{"x":51,"y":30,"id":32,"timeOffset":-50}]},"timestamp":1630354989735},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":71,"y":52,"id":35,"timeOffset":-492},{"x":71,"y":54,"id":35,"timeOffset":-222},{"x":68,"y":57,"id":35,"timeOffset":-166}]},"timestamp":1630354990244},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Johno","isChecked":false,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990507},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Johnoo","isChecked":false,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990643},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":67,"y":58,"id":35,"timeOffset":-365},{"x":67,"y":55,"id":35,"timeOffset":-60},{"x":67,"y":73,"id":39,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1630354990755},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":1,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354990939},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":6,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990940},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354990940},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":0,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354991050},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":2,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354991051},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Doeo","isChecked":false,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354991107},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Doeoo","isChecked":false,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354991250},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":67,"y":81,"id":39,"timeOffset":-438}]},"timestamp":1630354991264},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":68,"y":82,"id":39,"timeOffset":-489},{"x":126,"y":78,"id":39,"timeOffset":-426},{"x":337,"y":94,"id":26,"timeOffset":-376},{"x":683,"y":171,"id":4,"timeOffset":-325}]},"timestamp":1630354991783}],"timestamp":1630354993684}

{"events":[{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":737,"y":243,"id":4,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1630354993778},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":736,"y":243,"id":4,"timeOffset":-237}]},"timestamp":1630354994285},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":6,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354996225},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":6,"id":1},"timestamp":1630354996225}],"timestamp":1630354998684}
```

The player page has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Player</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@latest/dist/rrweb.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@latest/dist/rrweb.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var events = [{"events":[
                        [{"events":[{"type":0,"data":{},"timestamp":1630354988708},{"type":1,"data":{},"timestamp":1630354988711},{"type":4,"data":{"href":"https://track.mobiuslogistics.biz/","width":741,"height":615},"timestamp":1630354988712},{"type":2,"data":{"node":{"type":0,"childNodes":[{"type":1,"name":"html","publicId":"","systemId":"","id":2},{"type":5,"textContent":"\nTo change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.\nTo change this template file, choose Tools | Templates\nand open the template in the editor.\n","id":3},{"type":2,"tagName":"html","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":2,"tagName":"head","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":6},{"type":2,"tagName":"title","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"Recorder","id":8}],"id":7},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":9},{"type":2,"tagName":"meta","attributes":{"charset":"UTF-8"},"childNodes":[],"id":10},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":11},{"type":2,"tagName":"meta","attributes":{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"},"childNodes":[],"id":12},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":13},{"type":2,"tagName":"link","attributes":{"_cssText":".replayer-wrapper { position: relative; }.replayer-mouse { position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 20px; transition: left 0.05s linear 0s, top 0.05s linear 0s; background-size: contain; background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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\"); border-color: transparent; }.replayer-mouse::after { content: \"\"; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: rgb(73, 80, 246) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 100%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); opacity: 0.3; }.replayer-mouse.active::after { animation: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal none running click; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device { background-image: none; width: 70px; height: 70px; border-radius: 100%; margin-left: -37px; margin-top: -37px; border: 4px solid rgba(73, 80, 246, 0); transition: left 0s linear 0s, top 0s linear 0s, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device.touch-active { border-color: rgb(73, 80, 246); transition: left 0.25s linear 0s, top 0.25s linear 0s, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device::after { opacity: 0; }.replayer-mouse.touch-device.active::after { animation: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal none running touch-click; }.replayer-mouse-tail { position: absolute; pointer-events: none; }@keyframes click {\n0% { opacity: 0.3; width: 20px; height: 20px; }\n50% { opacity: 0.5; width: 10px; height: 10px; }\n}@keyframes touch-click {\n0% { opacity: 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; }\n50% { opacity: 0.5; width: 10px; height: 10px; }\n}"},"childNodes":[],"id":14},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":15},{"type":2,"tagName":"script","attributes":{"src":"https://track.mobiuslogistics.biz/js/rrweb-record.js"},"childNodes":[],"id":16},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":17},{"type":2,"tagName":"script","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"SCRIPT_PLACEHOLDER","id":19}],"id":18},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    ","id":20}],"id":5},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    ","id":21},{"type":2,"tagName":"body","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n        ","id":23},{"type":2,"tagName":"div","attributes":{},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n            ","id":25},{"type":2,"tagName":"form","attributes":{"action":"/action_page.php"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":27},{"type":2,"tagName":"label","attributes":{"for":"fname"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"First name:","id":29}],"id":28},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":30},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":31},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"text","id":"fname","name":"fname","value":"John"},"childNodes":[],"id":32},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":33},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":34},{"type":2,"tagName":"label","attributes":{"for":"lname"},"childNodes":[{"type":3,"textContent":"Last name:","id":36}],"id":35},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":37},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":38},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"text","id":"lname","name":"lname","value":"Doe"},"childNodes":[],"id":39},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":40},{"type":2,"tagName":"br","attributes":{},"childNodes":[],"id":41},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n                ","id":42},{"type":2,"tagName":"input","attributes":{"type":"submit","value":"Submit"},"childNodes":[],"id":43},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n            ","id":44}],"id":26},{"type":3,"textContent":" \n        ","id":45}],"id":24},{"type":3,"textContent":"\n    \n\n","id":46}],"id":22}],"id":4}],"id":1},"initialOffset":{"left":0,"top":0}},"timestamp":1630354988721},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":1},"timestamp":1630354988723},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":348,"y":208,"id":4,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1630354988725},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":378,"y":169,"id":4,"timeOffset":-415},{"x":372,"y":165,"id":4,"timeOffset":-167},{"x":192,"y":99,"id":26,"timeOffset":-117},{"x":104,"y":74,"id":39,"timeOffset":-67},{"x":95,"y":59,"id":26,"timeOffset":-16}]},"timestamp":1630354989233},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":1,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989556},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354989556},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":0,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989642},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":2,"id":32,"x":49,"y":28},"timestamp":1630354989642},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":81,"y":46,"id":32,"timeOffset":-469},{"x":53,"y":31,"id":32,"timeOffset":-418},{"x":51,"y":30,"id":32,"timeOffset":-50}]},"timestamp":1630354989735},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":71,"y":52,"id":35,"timeOffset":-492},{"x":71,"y":54,"id":35,"timeOffset":-222},{"x":68,"y":57,"id":35,"timeOffset":-166}]},"timestamp":1630354990244},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Johno","isChecked":false,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990507},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Johnoo","isChecked":false,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990643},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":67,"y":58,"id":35,"timeOffset":-365},{"x":67,"y":55,"id":35,"timeOffset":-60},{"x":67,"y":73,"id":39,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1630354990755},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":1,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354990939},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":6,"id":32},"timestamp":1630354990940},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":5,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354990940},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":0,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354991050},{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":2,"id":39,"x":67,"y":82},"timestamp":1630354991051},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Doeo","isChecked":false,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354991107},{"type":3,"data":{"source":5,"text":"Doeoo","isChecked":false,"id":39},"timestamp":1630354991250},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":67,"y":81,"id":39,"timeOffset":-438}]},"timestamp":1630354991264},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":68,"y":82,"id":39,"timeOffset":-489},{"x":126,"y":78,"id":39,"timeOffset":-426},{"x":337,"y":94,"id":26,"timeOffset":-376},{"x":683,"y":171,"id":4,"timeOffset":-325}]},"timestamp":1630354991783}],"timestamp":1630354993684}],
                        [{"type":3,"data":{"source":2,"type":6,"id":1},"timestamp":1630347964190}]
            ]}];
            const replayer = new rrweb.Replayer(events);
            replayer.play();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='player'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried everything I could think of to have it working but I'm getting

```
Uncaught Error: Replayer need at least 2 events.
    o index.ts:138
    <anonymous> player.php:8327
```

Any help would be appreciated please. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've shown an error log from a PHP server, but you haven't posted any server code.

Comment: The console log is a browser log, the var = events is the variable the the player is supposed to read, the server side code just saves the event and the content of the var= events is what is sent by PHP

Answer (score -1):

In variable events you have to pass two events. Where you pass only one events.

```
var events1 = [{"events":[{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":256,"y":6,"id":35,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1657012350677},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":171,"y":65,"id":22,"timeOffset":-463},{"x":131,"y":119,"id":50,"timeOffset":-411},{"x":128,"y":120,"id":50,"timeOffset":-323},{"x":107,"y":142,"id":3,"timeOffset":-271}]},"timestamp":1657012351191},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":109,"y":148,"id":3,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1657012351764},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":239,"y":135,"id":3,"timeOffset":-1352},{"x":314,"y":132,"id":50,"timeOffset":-1300},{"x":382,"y":124,"id":50,"timeOffset":-1248},{"x":393,"y":110,"id":47,"timeOffset":-1196},{"x":390,"y":35,"id":39,"timeOffset":-1144}]},"timestamp":1657012353168}]}];

 var events2 =[{"events":[{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":153,"y":2,"id":35,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1657012395458},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":0,"y":142,"id":3,"timeOffset":0}]},"timestamp":1657012396623},{"type":3,"data":{"source":1,"positions":[{"x":20,"y":112,"id":42,"timeOffset":-462},{"x":78,"y":30,"id":22,"timeOffset":-410}]},"timestamp":1657012397136}]}];

var events = events1.concat(events2);

const replayer = new rrweb.Replayer(events);
```